# table rows column for mobile view and for desktop view

Tags: html, css, html-table, tr

I need some CSS help to display my business hours schedules that simply has business day, business status (open or close), business open hour, business close hour input columns in html. Hours input field column has 2 buttons each (+ and -) for each hours input (buttons helps users click to enter value instead of typing the value critical feature for mobile/tablets to avoid typing). Issue I'm facing is for mobile and tablet view, all these columns have overflown the screen width thus requiring user to scroll horizontal to see rest of the hours columns.

Heres what I would like:

1. For desktop view (current table/tr/td layout for desktop view looks like this which is fine)

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9
```

2. For tablets/pad I want the same schedule layout to look like this

```
Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 
blank Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9
```

3. For mobile phones of all sizes I want the same schedule layout to look like this

```
Col1  Col2 Col3 
blank Col4 Col5 
blank Col6 Col7 
blank Col8 Col9
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the HTML fixed as a table and you can't alter it?

Comment: yes HTML is a fixed table no alteration in columns or rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting each row as a grid.

Here's an example:

```css
table {
  width: 100vw;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  tr {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  }
  td:nth-child(6n) {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  tr {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  td:nth-child(2n) {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col1 </td>
    <td>Col2 </td>
    <td>Col3 </td>
    <td class="move">Col4 </td>
    <td class="move">Col5 </td>
    <td class="move">Col6 </td>
    <td class="move">Col7 </td>
    <td class="move">Col8 </td>
    <td class="move">Col9 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ty for the tip css, however with your css except col1 all other columns are sent to grid which is messing all my alignment of the columns like puzzle, it is not properly putting columns in right place except for desktop view

Comment: Could you add more to your code in your questionso this problemis shown (with the content given it works OK).

Comment: Its a simple table tr td columns without any CSS as explained visually in my question there is no code I'm using for the table columns.

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet in your question which shows the problem, and which shows it with the code above as at the moment the code here works witth the HTML you have given. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example